# Why http requests sent by cURL give different result than browsers?

Tags: http, curl

In Google Chrome, I can view http headers sent and received by the browser. An interesting option is you can copy the whole request/response **as a cURL cmd**.

The problem is, each time I run the produced cURL command, although the server sends a **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**, but the **content-length** is zero which is not the case when the same requests are sent by the browser itself.

What do you thing could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an HTTP server with defense against DDoS attack.

The HTTP server might expect each request to contain something specific the to time and sequence of the operation. It might reside in headers or body as a special token.

My guess is each time the server may respond with a different cookie value, which makes sending 2 requests with the same cookie value invalid. Or it may be something using UTC time as parameter. Anyway there must be something in your request that doesn't pass the server side filtering.

--

Or similarly it may be a resource for one-off use. E.g. a temporary file prepared for one-off download. Once it's accessed, the file is not available anymore.

Comment: WOW! lots of new information did you give me... Now, if you don't mind, would you answer another BIG question of mine: "when I do something wrong inside the web page (with the browser), I receive a warning message. NO WHERE AT ALL, in the developer tools did I manage to track the message; no where in scripts, nor in the HTTP responses which I have already managed to track, nor in the main HTML file, ... I'm really running crazy since I have absolutely no clue as to where these messages come from. This has wasted a week of my life!!!

Comment: By the way, I'm guessing it has something to do with "Browser Time" which is being POSTed to the server each time I make a new request; and you're (again) right: I can also see a cookie coming from server, having a fresh value with each response. I'll try to play with them and let you (readers) know the result.

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani Maybe the messaged is stored as an encoded string, e.g. Base64, or even some more esoteric encoding scheme. And there may be other things that can further obfuscate the message, e.g. get data with ajax, run some logic with eval(), etc.

Comment: dear @cshu, thank you for your kind reply. You're right, I guess I need to dig deeper into the code (which is really HUGE) in order to find something useful. I appreciate your help...

Comment: chrome has a feature to help troubleshoot curl differences: https://lornajane.net/posts/2013/chrome-feature-copy-as-curl

Answer (score 3):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation.

I have just had an experience with this and what fixed it was surprising. In my situation I was logging into a server so I could upload a file, have the server do work on it, and then download the new file. I did this in Chrome first and used the dev tools to capture over 100 HTTP requests in this simple transaction. Most are simply grabbing resources I don't need if I am trying to do all of this from the command line, so I filtered out only the ones I knew at a minimum I should need.

Initially this boiled down to a GET to set the cookie and log in with a username and password, a POST to upload the file, a POST to execute the work on the file, and a GET to retrieve the new file. I could not get the first POST to actually work though. The response from that POST is supposed to be information containing the upload ID, time uploaded, etc, but instead I was getting empty JSON lists even though the status was 200 OK.

I used CURL to spoof the requests from the browser exactly (copying the User-Agent, overriding Expect, etc) and was still getting nothing. Then I started arbitrarily adding in some of the requests that I captured from Chrome between the first GET and POST, and low and behold after adding in a GET request for the JSON history before the POST the POST actually returned what it was supposed to.

TL;DR Some websites require more requests after the initial log in before you can POST. I would try to capture a successful exchange between the server and browser and look at all of the requests. Some requests might not be as superfluous as the seem.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't make a successful request to https://via.placeholder.com/50x50 from cURL. The requests look identical to me and works from the browser even in a fresh incognito session.

Answer (score 2):

If you send a GET request, and have some parameters, the url should be like:

```
http://www.example.com/login?user='abc'&pwd='123'
```

Make sure to use '\' to escape '&' in the url, the '&' is a special keyword to send process to background when using shell.

Otherwise, the above url will be truncated to:

```
http://www.example.com/login?user='abc'
```

Comment: This lead me on the right track, but I found it even easier to just put the URL in single quotes. (Unless the URL itself contains single quotes which then have to be escaped – but only them.)